# Changing tooltip shape for a series in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm adding a series to my Highcharts chart. I'm trying to make that specific series' tooltip have a certain shape. I know that you can change the tooltip shape for the whole chart, but I want each series to have a specific one. How do I accomplish this.

P.S. This doesn't work:

```
chart.addSeries({
     ...stuff...
     tooltip: {
          shape: "triangle-down"
     }    
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [API states](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.tooltip) that only a subset of properties are used from the `Series.tooltip` options. The `shape` attribute is not one of them. However, one way to get around this is to extend the `Tooltip.refresh` function to do a full redraw of the tooltip, and supplying the `shape` argument there.

For example:

```js
$(function() {
        (function (H) {
            H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function (proceed, pointOrPoints, mouseEvent) {
                this.update({ shape: pointOrPoints.series.tooltipOptions.shape });
                return proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            });
        }(Highcharts));


        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            tooltip: {
                shape: 'triangle-down', // Global shape
            },

            series: [{
                tooltip: {
                    shape: 'diamond' // Specific shape for series
                },
                data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
            }, {
                tooltip: {
                    shape: 'circle' // Specific shape for series
                },
                data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
            }, {
                tooltip: {
                    shape: 'square' // Specific shape for series
                },
                data: [0, 0, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
            }, {
                data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
            }],

        });
    });
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 310px;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

This shows overriding the `Tooltip.refresh` and then using `pointOrPoints.series.tooltipOptions.shape` to fetch the `tooltip.shape` for the specific series. Note that this will be more resource intensive as the tooltip is recreated for each `tooltip.refresh`, as the shape can only be altered upon label creation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The idea was to use unicode symbols within PointFormat option of the serie tooltip :

```
const serie: Highcharts.SeriesLineOptions = {
        name: 'Custom Tooltip Serie',
        ...,
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '▲ {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>'
        }
    };
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).